# Can the gravitational field be considered conservative despite the existence of singularities?

Tags: general-relativity, astrophysics, vector-fields, singularities

Assuming singularities are physical objects as opposed to mathematical artifiacts, can the gravitational field still be considered conservative? And if not, does this open a possibility of breaking the law of conservation of energy? Open to discussion on this one: I was a bit distracted in my calc class and it was mentioned a vector field isn’t simply connected it isn’t conservative. I’m probably missing something but a conversation about this would be incredibly interesting.

Comment: I've deleted the cosmology tag, since this doesn't seem related to cosmology. You also put in the general-relativity tag. I don't think there is a meaningful answer to this in the context of GR, since in GR there is no observable quantity corresponding to the newtonian gravitational field.

Answer (score 2):

The space $\mathbb R^3$ with isolated point singularities is however simply connected, so the problem actually does not exist. In the three space, to produce a multiply connected domain you should remove more than isolated points. You should remove lines at least (closed or infinitely extended).

However, also if the space is not simply connected, an irrotational vector field may still admit potential. Think of the static electric field for instance in the presence of a source given by an infinitely long line uniformly charged or a charged ring, it always admits potential nomatter topological problems of its spatial domain in view of the integral Maxwell laws.